# Passing Data from Watch to iPhone using Appgroups

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, appgroups

I am working on a project to pass data from an Apple Watch App to the iPhone App using Appgroups. My code is not working and I am not sure why. Hopefully someone can help me out! :)

Sending Data Apple Watch

```
@IBAction func senddata() {
    let group = "group.pairedapp"
    let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: group)
    let ok = "works"
    shared!.setValue(ok, forKey: "status")

    shared!.synchronize()    
}
```

Getting Data on iPhone

```
@IBAction func getWatchData(_ sender: Any) {    
    let group = "group.pairedapp"
    let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: group)

    let get = shared!.value(forKey: "status")
    if get != nil {
        print("works")
    }
    else{
        print("OO NO!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Use [`WCSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession)

Comment: Use WatchConnectivity for data sharing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365131/how-to-share-data-using-watch-connectivity-when-working-with-core-data/34410018#34410018

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of `watchOS2`, `watchOS` apps are no longer considered just extensions of their `iOS` counterpart and hence you cannot use `AppGroups` to share data between the two.

You should use the `WatchConnectivity` framework on `watchOS2+` to share data between your `watchOS` and `iOS` apps.

For more information, see the [Sharing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html) part of the WatchKit Programming Guide.